# RuntimeError: NumPy internal error: could not find function numpy.core._methods._amin

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Trying to run the following code:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets, svm 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing, neighbors, svm 

#reads the file and prints it out
df = pd.read_csv('cancer1.txt')
#repalaces all missing values with -99999 because when running 
the program python wil treat those missing values as an 
outlier
# Replace the unassigned values with -99999 and drop the id 
column
df.replace('?', 0, inplace=True)
df.drop(['id'], 1, inplace=True)

print(df)
# Get the features and labels
X1 = np.array(df.drop(['class'], 1))
y1= np.array(df['class'])
X=X1[:120]
y=y1[:120]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
def evaluate_on_test_data(model=None):
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
correct_classifications = 0
for i in range(len(y_test)):
    if predictions[i] == y_test[i]:
        correct_classifications += 1
accuracy = 100*correct_classifications/len(y_test) #Accuracy 
as a percentage
return accuracy
kernels = ('linear','poly','rbf')
accuracies = []
for index, kernel in enumerate(kernels):
model = svm.SVC(kernel=kernel)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
acc = evaluate_on_test_data(model)
accuracies.append(acc)
print("{} % accuracy obtained with kernel = {}".format(acc, 
kernel))
#Train SVMs with different kernels
svc = svm.SVC(C=1000,kernel='linear').fit(X_train, y_train)
rbf_svc = svm.SVC(C=1000,kernel='rbf', gamma=0.7).fit(X_train, 
y_train)
poly_svc = svm.SVC(C=1000,kernel='poly', 
degree=2).fit(X_train, y_train)

#Create a mesh to plot in
h = .02  # step size in the mesh
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                 np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

#Define title for the plots
titles = ['SVC with linear kernel',
      'SVC with RBF kernel',
      'SVC with polynomial (degree 2) kernel']


for i, clf in enumerate((svc, rbf_svc, poly_svc)):
# Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color 
to each
# point in the mesh [x_min, m_max]x[y_min, y_max].
plt.figure(i)

Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Paired, alpha=0.8)

# Plot also the training points
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.ocean)
plt.xlabel('')
plt.ylabel('')
plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())
plt.title(titles[i])

plt.show()

But after running it gives me the following error:
File "C:/Users/Jay/Documents/untitled5.py", line 48, in <module>
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
RuntimeError: NumPy internal error: could not find function 
numpy.core._methods._amin
```

the code will run up until the accuracy but after that, it would give that error. Any help would be to resolve this would be great.

Comment: Hi @Jay, welcome to stackoverflow. In order to make it easty to reproduce your issue, please fix the indentation on the python code block. Also, it would be helpful if you could post an example of what the file cancer1.txt contains. Also, what version of Python are you running?

Answer (score 0):

**It seems that the `numpy` installation is broken.**

**First, try this:**

```
import numpy
numpy.core._methods._amin
```

**This should return:**

```
<function numpy.core._methods._amin>
```

**If you still get the error then do the following in the terminal:**

```
pip install numpy
```